# Англо-русский переводчик(метод перевода)

Tags: c#

Реализовываю англо-русский и русско-английский переводчик на форме с использованием ООП. Возникли проблемы с переводом слов. Не могу перевести словосочетание, которое в другом языке состоит из одного слова. Например, bookcase (книжный шкаф) могу перевести на русский, а с русского на английский нет, так как в методе перевода разделяю слова пробелами.

```
class Translate
    {
        static string path = @"Dictionary.txt";
        public static int count = 1;
        public static string PathDef()
        {
            return path;
        }
        public static int direction = 1;
        public Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public Translate(int direction) //конструктор, в котором заполняется словарь из файла
        {
            string[] dictionary = File.ReadAllLines(PathDef(), Encoding.Default);

            foreach (string line in dictionary)
            {
                    string[] words = line.Split(' ');
                    if (direction == 1)
                        dict.Add(words[0], words[1]);
                    if (direction == 2)
                        dict.Add(words[1], words[0]);
            }
        }
        public string Translat(string text) //метод перевода
        {
            string[] textArray = text.Split(' ');
            string result = "";
            foreach (string word in textArray)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(word))
                {
                    result += dict[word] + " ";
                }
                else
                    result += "<???> "; //если нет в словаре
            }
            return result;
        }
}
```

Попыталась исправить метод, но выдаёт исключение "индекс находился вне границ массива"

```
string[] textArray = text.Split(' ');
string result = "";          
for (int i = 0; i < textArray.Length; i++)
{
      string word = textArray[i];
      if (textArray.Length > 1)
      {
          string word1 = textArray[i] + " " + textArray[i + 1]; #Индекс находился вне границ массива, если 2 слова
          if (dict.ContainsKey(word1))
                result += dict[word1] + " ";
          else
                result += "<???> ";
       }
       else if (dict.ContainsKey(word))
                result += dict[word] + " ";
       else
                result += "<???> ";
}
```

Comment: Не разделяйте слова пробелами в вашем файле, а разделяйте их запятыми или точкой с запятой. Вам поменять - только одно место придётся `line.Split(';');`. Это первая часть решения, самая очевидная. Вторая посложнее - как разделить слова на лексемы в поле ввода.

Comment: В файле слова разделила "-". Но также игнорирует

Comment: В файле не стоит использовать дефис. Слова типа "из-за", "по-простому" содержат дефисы. Точка с запятой в этом плане надёжнее.

Comment: Это не решило мою проблему. Мне нужно исправлять не конструктор, а  метод перевода

Comment: Разумеется это не решит, потому что это половина дела. Но без неё не двинуться дальше.

Comment: В методе перевода вам нужно сделать дополнительный шаг - не разбивать слова по пробелам, а пробовать сначала искать по два слова. Это решит вашу проблему. Итоговый перевод будет так себе, потому что реальные переводы так не делают, там совсем иные принципы (вот просто у вас для начала учёт склонений не реализован - "книжным шкафом" уже споткнётся), но для решения конкретной задачи сойдёт.

Comment: Благодарю! Попробую реализовать

Comment: Есть такой простой шаблон проектирования - **конечный автомат** (машина состояний). Поизучайте, очень поможет при решении этой задачи. А так же позволит при наличии классификации слов делать более аккуратный вывод.

Comment: Спасибо! Обязательно когда-нибудь ознакомлюсь с машиной состояний, но сейчас времени на это нет) Желательно уже сегодня полностью сделать переводчик

Comment: @AK, я пыталась исправить метод, но теперь работает только с одиночными словами